Mean motion as indication for satellite (evasion) maneuvers
I am interested in detecting satellite maneuvers, e.g., to avoid collissions.
As far as I understand the best publicly available data comes from TLEs although they have their own problems.
What is the "simplest" way to detect maneuvers.
As an example here
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/chinese-space-station-starlink-conjunctions-closer-look-jim-shell/
the mean motion is plotted and large differences betweeen TLEs are noted as indications for a maneuver.
Would that be sufficient or are there other sources or ways how to detect these maneuvers? I'm aware of the paper below but as far as I see, the algorithm is not publicly available.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355779339_Simplified_Approach_to_Detect_Satellite_Maneuvers_Using_TLE_Data_and_Simplified_Perturbation_Model_Utilizing_Orbital_Element_Variation

Check your last link to Researchgate https://i.sstatic.net/0boFJxeC.png Click the DOI link and you are taken to the actual published paper. You are in luck! Both the paper and it's supplemental section are Open Access so you can download them. Just after Figure 1, the text says "(see Supplement Section 2 for pseudo-code used in this algorithm)" If you download that, you will see their algorithm. I am not sure why this works better than just looking for bigger-than-average discontinuities in propagated positions between one TLE and the next, but I haven't read it yet.

Do you have a reference to your method or a ready-made program that does that?

Sorry if that was unclear. I meant whether there are ready-made tools for the "just looking for bigger-than-average discontinuities in propagated positions between one TLE and the next"

Oh I understand. I don't know myself, but you can give this a few days for people to see it. It takes 24 hours for daily users around the world to log in, and many people don't log in every day. Can you run Python programs? Or do you need something that runs stand-alone. I think it's going to be hard to find something that's ready to go.

Python would work. Given that I am not in the field building anything myself is probably unrealistic.
Ideally, I would just feed many TLEs and get indications for maneuvers. Thanks for your time!
